# Python lists, modules, and loops (syntax error)

Tags: python

currently learning Python but I'm a little stumped with a particular question.

I need to print the length of a list using a loop without the use of any built-in functions.

I understand that the following works when I input it:

```
listLength = 0

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for y in list1:
    listLength += 1
print(listLength)
```

However the question gives us a file that we cannot edit:

```
import function_lists

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

print("Length of list:", function_lists.listLength(list1))
```

In the editable file named function_lists i've done this:

```
def length(a_list)

    length = 0

    for y in list1:
        listLength += 1
```

Syntax error: list1 is not defined - from what I can tell is that I'm misunderstanding how modules work, shouldn't list1 be pulled out of the un-editable file via the `import function_lists` so it does work?

I'd ask my prac tutor but I don't have anything until late this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the parameter name, `a_list`, instead of the parameter you passed, `list1`. @Andy G pointed out, when declaring functions, you need to end the declaration with a colon(eg. `def function_name(args):`). Moreover, the default return value of a function is None so, as @RiaD pointed out, you should also return the `length` variable.

```
def length(a_list)

    length = 0

    for y in list1:
        listLength += 1
```

should be

```
def length(a_list):
    length = 0
    for y in a_list:
        length += 1
    return length
```

Comment: You are also missing a colon at the end of the def statement.

Comment: And return is also needed

Comment: Ah yeah. You initialized the variable `length` so you should use that one instead of `listLength`.

Comment: The function should be named `listLength`.